# taking handle of the current process (itself)

Tags: c++

Can i take a program handle?

Not the current process handle. Exactly the program handle.

For example, if we used the "GetCurrentProcess" function and just minimized the window and switched to the browser - we will take the browser handle, not a c++ program.

Comment: This is question unclear to me, could you please add more detail.  Note that `GetCurrentProcess`: _"...return value is a pseudo handle to the current process...."_ ie not a real handle. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocess

Comment: You are asking about the concept of "Focus". You might be asking "How to get the the handle of the process that owns the window that is currently in focus". The C++ language has no concept of other processes, you need to rely on your platform's specific API.